# How do I reorder the tracks in a Spotify playlist using the web player?

Tags: spotify, spotify-playlist

I'm using Google Chrome on Windows 7.  I can't drag and drop the tracks, and I see no option for changing the order.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, I believe the only way is to remove the songs and add them again in the order you want them. The song you add first will be at the top, the last one at the bottom.

Or add them to a new playlist in the order you want and remove the original one.

Comment: Despite users asking for this feature for YEARS, Spotify has done [nothing](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Accounts-and-Subscriptions/Created-a-playlist-and-cant-rearrange-songs/m-p/1591857/highlight/true#M260159) to fix it reliably.

Comment: It seems that missing the sort feature is by design: https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/Web-Player-Sorting-songs-on-a-playlist/idi-p/1243091 (Official status update Dec 2016 is "we've brought it to our teams internally. Right now we don't have plans for sorting tracks within your Spotify Playlists on the Web Player")